# Pandas Data Processing

Tags: python, pandas, data-preprocessing

I have two data frames as follow.

df1 :

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | x | y | z |

df2 :

|  | A | B | C | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 4 | 5 | 6 | p | q | r |

I wanted to make three data frames using these two like this.

ndf1 :

|  | A | B | C | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | id_0 |
|  | 4 | 5 | 6 | id_1 |

ndf2 :

|  | ID | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | id_0 | x | y | z |

ndf3 :

|  | ID | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | id_1 | p | q | r |

- ndf1 contains unique keys of both df1 and df2.
- ndf2 contains data from df1
- ndf3 contains data from df2

My questions are, Is this workflow possible with Python and Pandas? and What would be the best approach for that?

Comment: What should `ID` in all those dataframes come from?

Comment: @richardec ID represents uniques values of A, B and C

Comment: [index.intersection](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) and [index.difference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html).

Comment: @QuangHoang Could you please explain more!

Comment: instead of `'id_0'` and `'id_1'`, why not use the index of the rows in `df1` and `df2`? That could be cleaner. Also, putting example data in markdown tables is a pain (for you and for us): it's hard to replicate your setup by copy/pasting.

Comment: @PierreD Yes, using row indices is fine. But ID needs to be unique.  I added data to explain more about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I will differ a bit from your formulation, in order to:

1. follow the convention of Unix/Linux's [`comm`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/comm.1.html) command.
2. use the index of `df1`, resp. `df2`, to indicate where the rows come from (instead of creating `id_0` etc.)  If necessary, the index of `df1` and `df2` can be set to uniquely indicate provenance.

With this, you can do:

```py
ix1 = df1.columns.difference(df2.columns)  # unique to df1
ix2 = df2.columns.difference(df1.columns)  # unique to df2
ix3 = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)  # common

u1 = df1[ix1]
u2 = df2[ix2]
common = pd.concat([df1[ix3], df2[ix3]])
```

On your example data:

```py
>>> u1
   D  E  F
0  x  y  z

>>> u2
   G  H  I
0  p  q  r

>>> common
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
0  4  5  6
```

**Addendum**

Here is an example of how to modify the index of `df1` and `df2` to indicate unambiguously provenance:

```py
index1 = [f'df1_{i}' for i in df1.index]
index2 = [f'df2_{i}' for i in df2.index]

u1 = df1.set_axis(index1)[ix1]
u2 = df2.set_axis(index2)[ix2]
common = pd.concat([df1.set_axis(index1)[ix3], df2.set_axis(index2)[ix3]])
```

And now:

```py
>>> u1
       D  E  F
df1_0  x  y  z

>>> u2
       G  H  I
df2_0  p  q  r

>>> common
       A  B  C
df1_0  1  2  3
df2_0  4  5  6
```

Comment: The `common` df need to have unique IDs for each row and this ID refers to other df rows just like SQL tables with Foreign keys.

Comment: I put an example of generating that from the initial index. If that doesn't suit you, please describe the algorithm to generate (or where to find) `id_0` etc.

Comment: Thank you!!! Any unique ID is okay for me.  Now the problem is df1 and df2 contains many similar columns (like A, B, C), but they are not considered in creating the common/ndf1 data frame.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying that columns in common are not showing up in `common`? Are the columns _exactly_ the same (no sneaky spaces, etc.)?  Please provide `df1.head().to_dict(orient='records')` and `df2.head().to_dict(orient='records')`.

Comment: yes...exactly not all common columns, only a few selected ones are used to create common df.

Comment: won't happen unless somehow the apparently similar columns are actually different. As I said, please indicate the output the small samples as per my previous comment.

Comment: Following are the headers of two dfs.

df1: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XDNOtlhZnoCkPT17V5Y1rItemPtOx-Fn/view?usp=sharing

df2: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18pl_eXvAdrf_-zIaWU96gsXIFrcCC7_e/view?usp=sharing


Also the common df is made using only ["school","sex","age","address","famsize","Pstatus","Medu","Fedu","Mjob","Fjob","reason","nursery","internet"] columns.

Comment: I tried these google docs, and I get all the columns in common (no column unique to either `df1` or `df2`). Specifically, `common.columns.tolist()` gives me: `['Dalc', 'Fedu', 'Fjob', 'G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'Medu', 'Mjob', 'Pstatus', 'Walc', 'absences', 'activities', 'address', 'age', 'failures', 'famrel', 'famsize', 'famsup', 'freetime', 'goout', 'guardian', 'health', 'higher', 'internet', 'nursery', 'paid', 'reason', 'romantic', 'school', 'schoolsup', 'sex', 'studytime', 'traveltime']`

Comment: I need to select **only** `["school","sex","age","address","famsize","Pstatus","Medu","Fedu","Mjob","Fjob","reason","nursery","internet"] ` columns to the common df since there are many (e.g., Dalc, G1, G2, G3) common columns in df 1 and df2.

Comment: Oh, so you were not reporting a _problem_ (not all columns in common obtained in the result), but a _desire for a new functionality_: subset the result to only a few columns. Just make a list of the columns you want, and select that (`wanted = ['school', 'sex', ...]` then use `common[wanted]`).

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I'm trying your answer :) Once done I will accept and upvote your answer.  Highly appreciate your support on this problem....

Answer (score 0):

You could use pd.DataFrame.merge to merge df1 and df2. Then simply drop the unwanted columns from merged df to create ndf1

To create the ndf2 and ndf3 just drop the unwanted A, B, and C columns from df1 and df2 using pd.DataFrame.drop

**FYI**

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html